# Uncaught TypeError: URL is not a constructor using WHATWG URL object support for electron

Tags: node.js, url, electron, fs

I am trying to read a file using WHATWG URL object support [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_whatwg_url_object_support)

and I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: URL is not a constructor

here is my code:

```js
var fs = require("fs");                                     
const { URL } = require('url');
var dbPath = 'file://192.168.5.2/db/db.sqlite';
const fileUrl = new URL(dbPath);
```

Comment: "Added in: v7.6.0". Electron 1.6.11 is using 7.4.0.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I faced the same issue, then I looked into the url module and found a solution

**For Node V6** use,

```
const URL = require('url').Url;
```

or

```
const { Url } = require('url');
```

If you look into the module, it exports 5 methods one of which is Url, so if you need to access Url, you can use either of the two methods

Comment: I had to use `const URL = require('url').URL`

Comment: Sigh, it looks like the documentation is wrong here, it does not show the `.URL` https://nodejs.org/api/url.html in the various examples.

Comment: I think const URL = require('url').Url; will give you null values 


const URL = require('url').Url;
 var loginURL = new URL("http://exampe.com/xyz.html"); console.log(loginURL);

node version  8.4.0

Comment: @BiswajitMohanty, the above answer was posted for node version 6, for version 8, the method (const { URL } = require('url'); ) mentioned in the question should work fine.

Comment: @socketwiz, the documentation is not wrong, requiring a module with {} (const { URL } = require('url');) or using dot notation (const URL = require('url').URL) both must yield same response.

Answer (score 36):

Are you using Node 6 instead of Node 8?

## Node 6

```
const url = require('url');
const myUrl = url.parse('http://example.com');
const myUrlString = url.format(myUrl);
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url

## Node 8

```
const { URL } = require('url');
const myUrl = new URL('http://example.com');
const myUrlString = myUrl.toString();
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url

Comment: if you are managing multiple node environments - [`semver` can be helpful to determine which method to use based upon the node version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42536228/175679)

Answer (score 18):

### Node v10.0.0 and newer (currently Node v19.x)

**URL Class**

> v10.0.0 | The class is now available on the global object.

As mentioned here: [Node.js Documentation - Class: URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api)

So this should work without `require('url')`:

```
const myUrl = new URL('http://example.com');
```

Answer (score 10):

The docs you took this info out are for the `node` of version `8.4.0`.

If it does not work for you, that means that your `node` is of version `6.11.2`. Then, just change the letter case of `URL` -

```
const { Url } = require('url');
const myUrl = new Url('http://example.com');
```

because `url` module exports `Url`, not `URL`.