# Can't run browser platform. Error: url.URL is not a constructor

Tags: cordova

I can't run all my cordova projects in browser platform. Please help me.

```
$ cordova platform rm browser
Removing browser from cordova.platforms array in package.json
$ cordova platform add browser
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-browser@^6.0.0
Adding browser project...
$ cordova run browser
Updating manifest.json with push properties…
url.URL is not a constructor
```

THNKS

Comment: can you please check that "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738065/uncaught-typeerror-url-is-not-a-constructor-using-whatwg-url-object-support-for"

Comment: Use the search engine, or Google at least, for the next question..

Comment: Sorry but this solution doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 4):

Found a solution:
edit file platforms/browser/cordova/lib/run.js

Comment line 57:

```
// var projectUrl = (new url.URL(`http://localhost:${server.port}/${startPage}`)).href;
```

And replace it with new line:

```
var projectUrl = `http://localhost:${server.port}/${startPage}`;
```

Works for me!