# How I can change node versions for my project?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

At the moment npm install/build are using with node 8.9.4 (and with npm 5.6.0). And during deploying some code it always reinstall modules and I spend a lot of time. I know that it should cache packages but it doesn't work. So I want to update my node version and make the version 16.11.0 (with npm version 8.0.0) as stable. Because when I make `nvm list` it shows me with the green arrow near 8.9.4. Also when I make `node --v` it also shows me version 8.9.4.

So how I can update the node version to 16.11.0 in my project? Also it should be available for other developers. When they open the project and start npm install/build it should use node 16.11.0 with npm 8.0.0.

Comment: This link should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-package-json

Comment: If your entire team uses `nvm`, you can specify the required version in a [.nvmrc](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#nvmrc) file. On the command line, run `nvm use` with no extra argument and it'll pick up whatever is defined in that file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify [`engines`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#engines) in package.json
Just specify the node version or node range - you are expecting your stuffs to work on.

Answer (score 0):

The following post may help you: [How to change to an older version of Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718313/how-to-change-to-an-older-version-of-node-js)

Also, every developer will have to make sure they are running the correct version of node, since we have no way to "require" a specific version of node in package.json, unless you write code to manually enforce that during application startup. In that case, [Check for current Node Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656324/check-for-current-node-version)